# QGIS3 How to export shapefile symbology to scale?

Tags: shapefile, vector, qgis-3, scale

I'm looking how to export in QGIS3 a vector layer with a determined scale.
It was straightforward in QGIS2 when I was exporting to a shapefile I had the option symbology scale but it disapear in QGIS3 or maybe I'm missing something. 
The intent is to use the shapefile in another program.

Answer (score 1):

Shapefiles do not store scale or any style in their files. Yes, there is a Symbology export which I tried to make it work, and I have tried with `Feature symbology` enabled and `Symbol layer symbology` enabled. But in fact there was no effect at all and the shapefile was exported without any scale or symbology information stored in it.

[image]

Maybe this option was added to support other formats that can store scale and symbology but not shapefile.

Also I checked if using Symbology export option will add a new `.qml` file as symbology file alongside with the shapefile as kind of shortcut, but nothing happened and no extra  `.qml` file was added/exported.

In QGIS 3.4, it looks like the option of exporting shapefile and other vector formats was separated from exporting Symbology layer. Exporting shapefile/other vector formats is available by `right-click the layer in the table of contents -> Export -> Save Features as`, and you also export symbology including scale separately from `right-click the layer in the table of contents -> Export -> Save as QGIS Layer Style File`

[image]

Load the style as usual from `Layer Properties -> Style -> Load Style`

[image]

This will load the style with predefined scale and symbology onto the layer:

Scale value >= 100000 (1:250000), nothing appeared:

[image]

Scale value < 100000 (1:50000), style appeared:

[image]